# Google Maps API Geocode failed, status: OVER_QUERY_LIMIT

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-geocoder

I apologize if this is a duplicate. But I am still unable to fix this issue. I'm attempting to geocode multiple locations (around 20). I am currently getting `Geocode failed, status: OVER_QUERY_LIMIT`. I've attempted to set a timeout, from what I've seen on other Stack Overflow questions. However, this does not currently work for me. My geocoding is currently set up as such:

```
         setTimeout(function geocodeLocations(data) {
                    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': fullAddress }, function(data, status) {
                        if ( status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK ) {
                            var coordinates = data[0].geometry.location;
                            var lat = coordinates.lat();
                            var lng = coordinates.lng();


                            // sets the items in the marker 
                            var markerInfo = {
                                name: name,
                                lat: lat,
                                lng: lng,
                                locationStatus: locationStatus,
                                project: project,
                                date: FormattedDate,
                                storytellerFlag: storytellerFlag,
                                RegistrationLink: RegistrationLink,
                                ID: ID
                            };
                            map.setCenter(markerInfo);
                            createMarker(markerInfo);
                        } else {
                         console.log("Geocode failed, status: " + status);
                        }
                    });
                }, 2000);
```

Can anyone help me figure out how to allow more than 10 queries to be geocoded?

Comment: After 10 initial addresses, you can geocode at rate 1 request per second. This is a per session limit of the Maps JavaScript API, you cannot change it. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#UsageLimits

Comment: well, it appears we are sharing our query limit with another team. The API key is being shared, so there really isn't anything that can be done. @xomena